# Android Studio Gradle sync failed: Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: java, android, gradle, daemon

I open Android studio after several weeks and I see this error in messages View:

Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDdfV.png) user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

1. First I do other instructions in stackoverflow but there's no progression:
2. Then I removed C:\Users\Users.gradle  directory
   I changed heap size in gradle.properties and I Added this line at end of file org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m
   but no promotion.

what can I do for it?
thank's alot.

[image: This is my error]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the logs in `~/.gradle/daemon/<your-gradle-version>` to get more insight about the problem, in my case it was `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind` exception. I was using my computer as a hotspot for my phone and I realized that somehow it was preventing the deamon from binding, disabling the hotspot solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks man. Even in 2021, with Android Studio 4.1.1, they have not addressed this issue. If hotspot is turned on in windows 10 then Android Studio takes up huge ram running multiple instances of java.exe and throws "Unable to start the daemon process" error.